# Can you destructure a result from an SWR query?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, undefined, swr, destructure

I have a very simple query to an external API:

```
 const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(x=>x.json())
 const {data:{results}, error} = useSWR("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",fetcher)
```

Whenever I use it like this to destructure the data variable, I get an error saying that "results" is not defined. I can only access results as "data.results", is this a normal behavior?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')

Comment: The variable seems to take some time get the response back from the external API, because it does get it later if I conditionally render the variable and receive it as just "data" and not "data:{results}".

Comment: It's `data` which is `undefined` initially. You can't destructure `undefined`

Comment: How can I wait for the result using SWR and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data` isn't resolved, then at build time you can't deconstruct like that. If you happen to use `typescript`, maybe it'll be more clear. Since I bet `data` has to have type `whateverType | null`. THe `null` prevents the deconstruction at the compile time.

In short, just use `data`. And then `if (data.results) {}` at the runtime then.

Comment: Yes. I was rendering the result with a condition in runtime, but I thought I could do the destructuring during build time. Oh well. I guess I have to settle for rendering conditionally during runtime as {data && data.results.map(res=><div> ... </div>)}